# Jekyll post counts specific to custom front matter

Tags: tags, yaml, jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I spent the last several hours scouring the depths of stackoverflow along with other amazing Jekyll tutorial sites, and have yet to find a solution to this particular issue. =[

Instead of using site.tags or site.categories, I created my own custom label named "subcategories" under the category 'blog'. The goal is to try to get a post-count for each. The tutorials I've found have worked for both categories AND tags perfectly, just not custom front matter.

Some of my subcategories are written like this:

```
[design]
[gaming]
[design, gaming]
```

I'm looking for a code that will increment the post count by 1 as it realizes there's a post that contains the subcategory. Since I am not using a plugin, the complete list of subcategories are actually listed separately in a data .yml file (in addition to start of my posts).

Here is one of my **many** pitiful attempts at writing this:

```
<ul class="blog__sidebar__subcategories m-t-s">
  {% for subcategory in site.data.subcategories %}

      <a class="blog__sidebar__subcategories__item" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/blog/{{ subcategory.class }}">
      <li>{{ subcategory.class }}

          {% assign counter = '0' %}
          {% assign subcat_data == site.data.subcategories %}
            {% for post in site.categories.blog  %}
            {% if subcat_data == post.subcategories %}
              {% capture counter %}{{ counter | plus: '1' }}{% endcapture %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            ({{ counter }})
      </li>
      </a>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Problems I've found include the output having constant duplicates, or spitting out "design,gaming" as one entity. This results in things like:

```
design | 6 
gamingdesign | 6 
gaming | 6 
gaming | 6
```

Here's how my .yml file looks (simple):

```
- class: design

- class: gaming
```

And my code prior to attempting to add a post count (which worked!):

```
<ul class="blog__sidebar__subcategories m-t-s">
  {% for subcategory in site.data.subcategories %}


      <a class="blog__sidebar__subcategories__item" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/blog/{{ subcategory.class }}">
      <li>{{ subcategory.class }}</li>
      </a>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Also please let me know if I accidentally violated any social etiquette of stackoverflow. First time posting! Thank you a million.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll is not playing well with user arrays. I think you'd better stick to Jekyll's existing mechanisms.

So, you can use **tags** for subcategories.

```
---
layout: post
date: 2014-08-14 07:51:24 +02:00
title: Your title
categories: [ blog ]
tags:
  - design
  - gaming
---
```

And your loop can be

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}

  {% comment %}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    tag = Array [
            "design",
            Array [
              #Jekyll:Post @id="/blog/1993/02/08/index",
              #Jekyll:Post @id="/blog/1991/08/14/index"
            ]
          ]

    Values in this tag array are :
      - tag[0] -> "design"
      - tag[1] -> an Array of posts that have the design tag

    Here, we can already do a  "{{ tag [0] }} : {{ tag[1] | size }}" 
    that will give us the count for each tag's posts array.

    But if one post insn't in "blog" category but has a tag used 
    in the "blog" category, it will be counted here.

    Where must count only posts that are in the "blog" category.
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++{% endcomment %}

  {% assign counter = 0 %}

  {% for post in tag[1]  %}
    {% if post.categories contains "blog" %}
      {% assign counter = counter | plus: 1 %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% comment %}+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  Only print counter if the current tag has "blog" posts
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++{% endcomment %}
  {% if counter > 0 %}
      <p>{{ tag[0] }} : {{ counter }}</p>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi there! Yowza, that worked swimmingly. [This](https://gist.github.com/huyhong/d59be327d47181cb4421) plugin to filter with front matter was also brought to my attention that works (though not resorting to a plugin was preferred for me).

Both the plugin and your solution work wonderfully! Thank you so much for your help. I s'pose I'll cross my fingers in the meantime for user arrays to play nicer in Jekyll?